# Install packages in Ansible conditionally

Tags: jenkins, ansible, packer

Here is what I'm ultimately trying to achieve. I want to have a layered AMI system in AWS with Foundation->Base->Specialized Base->Application.

I'm looking to bake as much of the configuration as I can into these AMIs. The tools that I am using to accomplish this are Jenkins, Packer and Ansible.

The problem that I am having is that I want ansible to only install certain packages on instances that are set for production. I initially thought I could just do something like this

```
{ role: <<package_name>>, when: "{{ lookup('env', 'PROD') }}"  }
```

But that is looking on the host machine and not the AWS target. I'm trying to re-evaluate my process here and wanted to see if anyone had a better suggestion on how to limit the install of certain packages to certain machines. I know I could create a production base and a non production base, but that will double all of the downstream AMIs that I have and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Flipping the question on its head a little, what kind of package would you want in production but not elsewhere in your pipeline? Does that not limit the effectiveness of your pipeline? And is there any reason not to install it outside of production?

Comment: Good question. For this particular use case it would be a monitoring agent that we would pay for per install. I only want this monitoring agent baked into production systems. I could do this when the instance boots up via user_data or something, but I'd rather have it baked into the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables), `{{ ansible_env.SOME_VARIABLE }}` should work.

Comment: Thank you. So now I have to figure out why my Packer script is not setting the variable correctly. That is the topic of a different question. :)